# Create pub/sub notification for subdirectory, what is the best way? topic level filtering or subscriber level filtering

Tags: google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I want to create a pubsub topic to pubslish messages from a folder update in a GCS bucket.
Two options are available for this.
Create topic with `-p`, and create subscriber with "

```
hasPrefix(attributes.name, "co")
```

"

which is the best approach for pubsub topic creation for a GCS folder updates?